# Как правильно писать тесты Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

Есть простой метод

```
$userBalance = new UserBalance();
$userBalance->setUserId($user);
$userBalance->setBalance($money);
$this->entityManager->persist($userBalance);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Хочу написать для него тест, на добавление записи. В Laravel это делается легко, а тут небольшие трудности появились)

Сам тест выглядит примерно так

```
$client = static::createClient();

$data = [
   'user_id' => 1,
   'balance' => 100,
   'hold' => 0,
];

$client->request('POST', '/api/v1/add-money', [
   'body' => json_encode($data),
]);
```

Тест ругается что user_id не может иметь null значение. Данные из $data в него не приходят.

Comment: Ну так проблема получается в экшене, что обрабатывает роут `add-money`. Мы ж не видим что в этом экшене происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать json вместо body, вот так:

```
$client = static::createClient();

$data = [
   'user_id' => 1,
   'balance' => 100,
   'hold' => 0,
];

$client->request('POST', '/api/v1/add-money', [
   'json' => $data,
]);
```